# php - extract text between parenthesis, single quotes and double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract text between parenthesis, single quotes and double quotes. I have made it for single and double quotes, but I cant make it for the third parameter, parenthesis:

for example:

```
<img src="/path/to/the/file.jpg"></div>
<img src='/path/to/the/file2.png'></div>
<div style="background:url(/path/to/the/file555.gif)"></div>
```

I want to extract:

```
/path/to/the/file.jpg
/path/to/the/file2.png
/path/to/the/file555.gif
```

and this is the regex expression I am using:

```
preg_match_all('/(["\'])(.*(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif))\1/m', $subject, $matches)
```

or even this one:

```
preg_match_all('/(["\'])([^"\']*(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif))\1/m', $subject, $matches)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=['"\(])[^"())\n']*?(?=[\)"'])
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/12

```
$re = "/(?<=['\"\\(])[^\"()\\n']*?(?=[\\)\"'])/m"; 
$str = "<img src=\"/path/to/the/file.jpg\"></div>\n<img src='/path/to/the/file2.png'></div>\n<div style=\"background:url(/path/to/the/file555.gif)\"></div>"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: there is a problem with this code in this demo as you see. The text between parenthesis starts from the `background:...` and its preceding double quote

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I check it in my RegexBuddy and it gives me and error regarding zero-length matches: Your regular expression may find zero-length matches. Is that a problem?!

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat use `(?<=['"\(])[^"())\n']+?(?=[\)"'])`

Comment: `(?<=['"\(])[^"())\n']*(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)(?=[\)"'])` this works perfectly.

Comment: someone downvoted not only answers, but also the question :-|

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat dats a ritual here...dont worry...i have upvoted urs

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the regex:

```
[\"\'\(]+(\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\.]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png))[\)\"\']+
```

Comment: that looks horrific, can you explain what it's actually doing?

Comment: I just started with \" or \' or \( and then go to slashes up to 3 level and then go to dot which follows jpg or gif or png and ends with \" or \' or \).